# What is special about the "Steam Special Edition" of Tropico 3 and 4?

Tags: steam, tropico-4, tropico-3

The latest [Humble Weekly sale](https://www.humblebundle.com/weekly) features games from Kalypso Media, amongst them Tropico 3 and 4, marked as "Steam Special Edition" on the sales page

[image]

What's so special about the Steam Special Edition of these two games?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Taking a look at each of the game store pages on steam we see this.

**[Tropico 3](http://store.steampowered.com/app/23490/):**

> The Steam Special Edition of Tropico 3 contains the following additional content:

Two additional maps for the sandbox mode:

- Verde Playa
- Coco Chico Map

Two additional costumes for the el presidente avatar editor:

- Female Avatar: Casual Clothes
- Male Avatar: Casual Clothes

Two additional accessories for the el presidente avatar editor:

- Female Avatar: Baseball Hat
- Male Avatar: Commie Hat

**[Tropico 4](http://store.steampowered.com/app/57690/?snr=1_7_15__13):**

> Special Edition
>   ...includes an exclusive island (Isla Nublar) and El Presidente avatar costume (Luchador) and 50 Steam achievements. El Presidente is back to rule it all!

Comment: They added Isla Nublar but not dinosaurs?  How disappointing.